# hadoop WordCount stuck at map 0% reduce 0%

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm a chinese student and a beginer on hadoop 2.7.1. I will appreciate you if you could solve my problem.
When I run hadoop WordCount example recently on pseudo-distributed, it is stuck at map 0% and reduce 0%.

The log of the job is like this:

```
……
2017-05-14 16:32:55,939 INFO [main]         org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: yarn.client.max-cached-nodemanagers-proxies : 0
2017-05-14 16:32:55,957 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: job_1494750737018_0001Job Transitioned from INITED to SETUP
2017-05-14 16:32:55,960 INFO [CommitterEvent Processor #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler: Processing the event EventType: JOB_SETUP
2017-05-14 16:32:55,988 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: job_1494750737018_0001Job Transitioned from SETUP to RUNNING
2017-05-14 16:32:56,023 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.RackResolver: Resolved Gil to /default-rack
2017-05-14 16:32:56,034 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl: task_1494750737018_0001_m_000000 Task Transitioned from NEW to SCHEDULED
2017-05-14 16:32:56,036 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl: task_1494750737018_0001_r_000000 Task Transitioned from NEW to SCHEDULED
2017-05-14 16:32:56,038 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_1494750737018_0001_m_000000_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from NEW to UNASSIGNED
2017-05-14 16:32:56,038 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_1494750737018_0001_r_000000_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from NEW to UNASSIGNED
2017-05-14 16:32:56,039 INFO [Thread-50] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: mapResourceRequest:<memory:1024, vCores:1>
2017-05-14 16:32:56,055 INFO [Thread-50] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: reduceResourceRequest:<memory:1024, vCores:1>
2017-05-14 16:32:56,073 INFO [eventHandlingThread] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Event Writer setup for JobId: job_1494750737018_0001, File: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/gil/.staging/job_1494750737018_0001/job_1494750737018_0001_1.jhist
2017-05-14 16:32:56,935 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Before Scheduling: PendingReds:1 ScheduledMaps:1 ScheduledReds:0 AssignedMaps:0 AssignedReds:0 CompletedMaps:0 CompletedReds:0 ContAlloc:0 ContRel:0 HostLocal:0 RackLocal:0
2017-05-14 16:32:56,983 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor: getResources() for application_1494750737018_0001: ask=3 release= 0 newContainers=0 finishedContainers=0 resourcelimit=<memory:0, vCores:0> knownNMs=1
2017-05-14 16:32:56,984 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:32:56,984 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:32:56,984 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:32:56,985 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:32:57,988 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:32:57,988 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:32:57,988 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:32:57,988 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:32:58,991 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:32:58,991 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:32:58,991 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:32:58,991 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:32:59,994 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:32:59,994 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:32:59,994 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:32:59,994 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:33:01,000 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:33:01,000 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:33:01,001 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:33:01,001 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:33:02,003 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:33:02,003 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:33:02,004 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:33:02,004 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:33:03,006 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:33:03,007 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:33:03,007 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:33:03,007 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:33:04,009 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:33:04,010 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:33:04,010 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:33:04,010 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:33:05,014 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:33:05,014 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:33:05,014 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:33:05,014 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:33:06,019 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:33:06,019 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:33:06,020 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:33:06,020 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:33:07,022 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:33:07,022 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:33:07,022 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:33:07,022 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:33:08,025 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:33:08,025 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:33:08,025 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:33:08,025 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
2017-05-14 16:33:09,027 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Ramping down all scheduled reduces:0
2017-05-14 16:33:09,028 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Going to preempt 1 due to lack of space for maps
2017-05-14 16:33:09,028 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Recalculating schedule, headroom=<memory:0, vCores:0>
2017-05-14 16:33:09,028 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
……
……
……
```

And then it recycle all the time.

Here is my yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>
        <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>2200</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>500</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Here is my mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:10020</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:19888</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:9001</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

And this is logs/hadoop-*.out:

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15001
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15001
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I suspect there it is related with my hard disk space which only remains 5.6GB. Because when I clean up it from 3.xGB to 5.6GB, it was stuck at accepted state and will not run. But after I clean up it a little, it begin to run but stick at map 0% reduce 0%.

Besides when I execute a hive which will create a map-reduce job like `INSERT INTO xx VALUES(xxx);` It will also stick at map 0% reduce 0%.

Some Environment for me:

Ubuntu 14.04 64

hadoop-2.7.1

JAVA-8

What should I do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: GIl it is memory issue in you HDFS there is space  crunch to write interim data .

Answer (score 2):

Use default xml settings, it will resolve your issue, as you are limiting cluster resource ,there is a chance of miss calculation, 
The word **'default'** means do not define any specification related to memory
In your case : **remove**

```
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>2200</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>500</value>
</property>
```

and then try , if it works take a look on https://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/ link for better understanding how to set cluster resource.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me :
1. Define all the cluster nodes in the /etc/hosts of theirs with the name of host.
2. In the all of the setting files (hdfs-site, yarn-site, mapred-site) set master node with the defined name.

I think the use of different names in /etc/hosts with host names maybe the cause of this failure.